# If I don't include a dependency in the useEffect array, will it be stale inside the closure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Example:

```js
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(0)
const [bar, setBar] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => { computation(foo, bar) }, [foo])
```

Will the value of `bar` inside the `useEffect` closure be stale? I'm asking because in one of my applications, I forgot to include the `bar` in the deps array and it seemed like it was still up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of, but not exactly. Staleness won't really be an issue, but *whether the hook runs at all* will be, because you're using `useEffect` rather than something like `useCallback`.

Using `[foo]` means that it'll run when `foo` changes. If your other code is set up that whenever `bar` changes, `foo` has or will also be changed as well, then when the component re-renders, the new values of both will then be seen by the effect hook.

But if you change `bar` without changing `foo`, the effect won't run at all.

You *would* have a stale closure problem, if `bar` changed when `foo` didn't, if you were using `useCallback` or `useMemo`, among others, because those save a value in an outer variable (which can then be called or passed to other components).

Comment: Got it. So the lesson here is, the values inside of a `useEffect` will always be the freshest values. Of course, if I intentionally omit a dependency then I risk the callback not running, but insofar as I only want the callback to run when `foo` changes (even though `bar` changes more frequently), but each time `foo` changes I want access to the freshest value of `bar`, this is ok

Comment: Right. If you're dealing with exhaustive-deps, in my experience, it's *very* useful for `useCallback` and `useMemo` (because those can have stale values), and not useful for `useEffect` (because those values won't be stale)

Comment: I assume you meant `useMemo`?

Comment: Hmm, from experience `useCallback` has never fixed my stale state issues - I either have to include it within the dependency array or save it as a `ref`. One of the most annoying things about React.

Answer (score 0):

It won’t be stale within the effect, but the effect won’t re-run when `bar` changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here you should understand when useEffect will work,

`useEffect(() => { computation(foo, bar) } )` -> Will execute when any of the state in the component changes.

`useEffect(() => { computation(foo, bar) }, [foo])` -> Will execute while mounting and during the 'foo' state changes.

`useEffect(() => { computation(foo, bar) }, [])` -> Will execute only while the component is mounting for the first time.

So if you don't include the dependency. The useEffect will be called every time any state of the component changes.